# convert sql to activeRecprd select stetement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do something like this but using activeRecord:

> SELECT id FROM users WHERE userNum = 234234;

what is the equivalent active record for the above sql statement ?

I tried to do something like this which was suggested @Sebastian and it didn't work.

```
@getID = User.select(:id).where('userNum = ?', 234234)
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to select records based on the userNum. If so try:

```
userNum = 234234
@getId = User.where(id: userNum)
```

That will get you an active record relation with all records that match the criteria. As a bonus, if you want more matches you can pass an array to it as well.

```
userNums = [1,2,3,4]
@getId = User.where(id: userNum)
```

Comment: When I try to print like this `<h1>This is the new ID: <%=  @getId %></h1>  ` I get this something like this _This is the new ID: #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004d9a270>_ Do u know why is that ? Thanks

Comment: You have the object. <%= @getId.id %> if you have one user. To make you code more readable it should be `@selected_users = User.where(id: userNum)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I get `undefined method 'id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation` do u have any idea why is that ? Thanks

Comment: What is the result of ‘@getId.count’ and ‘@getId.first’?

Comment: `undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass` and `undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: `nil` that's all you need to know. It means that you selected no records. Chances are that you do not have any users in your db with an id of 234234. So if you have a column in your db that is userNum then use: `@getId = User.where(userNum: userNum)`

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate ur help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
userNum = 234234
@getId = User.where(userNum: userNum).pluck(:id).last
```